# Adding header to angular POST causes request body to be empty

Tags: angularjs, http-post, preflight

I am using angular to POST a file to an Amazon S3 bucket. In order to get the bucket to accept the request I am attempting to add an Upgrade-Insecure-Requests header to it, when I do so, the request no longer has a body.

This code correctly sends the request body:

```
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: responseData.url,
  data: postData,
  headers: {"Content-Type": undefined},
  transformRequest: angular.identity
})
```

While this code results in an empty request body:

```
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: responseData.url,
  data: postData,
  headers: {"Content-Type": undefined,
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"},
  transformRequest: angular.identity
})
```

What could be causing this?

**EDIT :** I discovered the reason that there was no request body is because a preflight OPTIONS request was being sent to S3. I added a CORS policy to the bucket allowing the OPTIONS and POST methods, so now the OPTIONS request returns correctly.

However after the OPTIONS response is received no POST is made, even though the POST should meet the requirements.

These are the request headers of the OPTIONS:

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: tesssssst-aws-cms.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: https://s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control, upgrade-insecure-requests
Accept: */*
Referer: https://s3.amazonaws.com/tesssssst-aws-cms/HTML/upload.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,th;q=0.2
```

These are the response headers of the OPTIONS:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: SQaOyODgprPIRe8uq3YEZBDXzVcUjyYc2GpLsZwmIwdII+FVIgOGQXokIzXTsBcIaOITgwrk8Zw=
x-amz-request-id: 07EE6477F2B3273C
Date: Thu, 08 Sep 2016 07:12:58 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: cache-control, upgrade-insecure-requests
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Content-Length: 0
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

}]);

Comment: @mehrdad Adding this breaks another currently working POST request on the page. Is there any way of adding this specifically to the request?

Comment: I use this too for sending data to header $http({
                    url: $scope.path + '/Account/EditUserAngular',
                    method: 'Post',
                    headers: {
                        'RequestVerificationToken': $scope.antiForgeryToken,
                        'IsMobile': "true",
                        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
                    },
                    data: {
                        model: $scope.UserEditViewModel,
                    }
                })

Comment: Adding the "X-Requested-With" header to the request headers has unfortunately not changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

**"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"**
  causing your post request to be sent as OPTIONS I faced the same issue so i remove the above line and it worked.
After that I am facing new Error CrossDomain issue but, when i check with fiddler everything is fine.
That's the browser(Chrome) issue.